# Fastest way to fetch records from remote sql server and save to local sql database using DataTable

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a customer table with over 100000 records in a remote sql server database.

```
Customer table
--------------
ID
Name
Phone
Occupation
Gender
```

I also have a list of 4000 customer id's.

What will be the fastest way to fetch customer data from remote sql server and save to local sql database using DataTable in .NET.

I will also be interested in any different way to achieve that.

**What I have tried:**

I made use of the IN statement, but it throws an error when id's are more than 3000:

```
select * from customertable where id in ('CUS1','CUS2','CUS3','CUS4','CUS5',....'CUS4000')
```

I would have inserted customer ids in a temp table and joined, but the two database are not hosted on the same server.

Comment: Use a temp table instead of hard coding 4000 values. Then you can simply join to it. This is exactly the kind of thing temp tables were designed for.

Comment: What sort of performance numbers are you seeing for the approach you have tried so far?

Comment: in general the absolute fastest way to ship data between servers is to BCP it out, and BCP it in.  No transactions, no safety, it's barely SQL :)

Comment: +1 for bulk copy. Especially if you have a known structure. I have not found anything that compares to the speed.

Comment: I can only read from the remote database and not write to it. Thereby I can't make use of a temporal table and join.
Can you help with another way of achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one option is to parse your list and perform a join.  **If 2016+,** you could use string_split().

```
Declare @List varchar(max) = 'CUS1,CUS2,CUS3,CUS4,CUS5,CUS6,CUS7,CUS8,CUS9,...'

Select A.* 
 From customertable A
 Join (
        Select RetVal = B2.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
         From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@List,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as B1 
         Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B2(i)
      ) B on A.ID=B.RetVal
```

> **EDIT**

I'm a little confused over your design, but tou can generate @List with something like this.

```
Declare @List varchar(max) = (Select Stuff((Select ',' +ID From #YourTemp  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
```

Comment: Thanks for the query but the sql server version is 2012

Comment: @user1519220 I should add, the XML Parse is very fast, just a nudge behind the tally approach and does not require a TVF.

Comment: This is the first time I'm using a query like this. I have learnt a new thing today.
Please can the value if @List be replaced with a select statement?
so that customer ids can be fetched from a temporal table

eg. 

Declare List varchar(max) = (select ID from temp)

Comment: @user1519220 See EDIT

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Comment: @user1519220 Happy to help